# Desktop MySQL-database manager with PHP tunnel script for OS X

Tags: mysql, macos

I'm looking for a good desktop-application (preferably on OSX) to manage my MySQL-databases on a shared host.
That host doesn't allow external connections though and I also can't connect via SSH

For example Navicat SQL can circumvent this limitation by having an intermediate PHP-script on the webserver to which the desktop-application sends its data.
Sadly I can't recall the name of the application and whether it was good or existed on OS X.

Do you know any?

Comment: If host doesn't allow external connections how on earth do you expect to be able to manage?

Comment: by calling a script which resides on the server. Navicat can do this for example.